# How to learn Digamma Function and how to take derivative of Gamma function?

Tags: special-functions

How can I learn polygamma function?(More precisely digamma function)As I was learning Bessel Function of Second kind expressed in terms of power series digamma function is used.I have firm-grasp in Calculus(Single and Multivariable).But no exposure to Complex Analysis.Is it necessary to have idea in Calculus of Complex variable to learn Gamma function completely?Can we expressed power series of Bessel Function of Second kind without using diagamma function using it factorial notation and how to derive it?

Comment: Have you already learned the [hypergeometric one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1310861/73025)?

Comment: No,I never learn hypergeometric function yet.

Comment: No,I never learn hypergeometric function yet.Is it mandatory?If yes,then how to study it?

Comment: Why do you focus on  these particular functions? If you have not studied complex analysis yet, you should be grateful - this is perhaps the most beautiful secret garden there is to explore in mathematics.